# How can I use be generic to result of linq query?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, generics, linq-to-entities, entity

Be first, my English is not very good. So I am sorry about that. :)

My question as the title. I have two tables on my database:

- Siniflar (SinifId, SinifAdi, Kapasite, OgretmenId)
- Ogretmenler (OgretmenId, Ad, Soyad, Brans)

Query:

```
  var siniflar = (from s in db.Siniflar 
                  join o in db.Ogretmenler 
                  on s.OgretmenId equals o.OgretmenId 
                  select new { s.SinifId, s.SinifAdi, s.Kapasite, o.Ad }).ToList();
```

I want to use the result of the query as a generic, like this:

```
  public List<Siniflar> SiniflariListele() 
  { 
   var siniflar = (from s in db.Siniflar 
                  join o in db.Ogretmenler 
                  on s.OgretmenId equals o.OgretmenId 
                  select new { s.SinifId, s.SinifAdi, s.Kapasite, o.Ad }).ToList();
   return siniflar; 
  }
```

But I get an error. Because the result is anonymous types.

Error: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>` to `System.Collections.Generic.List<Entity.Siniflar>`

How Can I use be generic result. What Can I do for that?

---

**I changed question:**

Class:

```
public class RSiniflar
{
    public int SinifId { get; set; }
    public string SinifAdi { get; set; }
    public int Kapasite { get; set; }
    public string OgretmenAdiSoyadi { get; set; }
}
```

Metod:

```
    public List<RSiniflar> SiniflariListele()
    {
        List<RSiniflar> siniflar = (from s in db.Siniflar
                        join o in db.Ogretmenler
                        on s.OgretmenId equals o.OgretmenId
                        select new RSiniflar
                        {
                            SinifId = s.SinifId,
                            SinifAdi = s.SinifAdi,
                            Kapasite = s.Kapasite,
                            OgretmenAdiSoyadi = o.Ad + ' ' + o.Soyad
                        }).ToList();
        return siniflar;
    }
```

But now error to query: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I think, there are a problem on my query... I get an error same when query to var type...

Comment: I believe `Siniflar` entity does not have `Ad` property. How you are going to return it?

Comment: You need an default constructor on RSiniflar

Answer (score 0):

You can return typed list, but you can't return a list of anonymous type. So you need to create a class which will handle your results:

```
public class A
{
    public int SinifId { get; set; }
    public int SiniAdi { get; set; }
    public int Kapasite { get; set; }
    public int Ad { get; set; }
}
```

And then use it in your query, instead of anonymous objects:

```
public List<A> SiniflariListele() 
{ 
    var siniflar = (from s in db.Siniflar 
                    join o in db.Ogretmenler 
                    on s.OgretmenId equals o.OgretmenId 
                    select new A {
                        SinifId = s.SinifId,
                        SinifAdi = s.SinifAdi,
                        Kapasite = s.Kapasite,
                        Ad = o.Ad
                    }).ToList();
    return siniflar; 
}
```

*You could do the same with an existing class (e.g. `Siniflar`), but you have to be sure that this class has all necessary properties.*

Comment: I changed question. Can you look now?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `new { property1, property2 }`, create new `Siniflar`'s in your `select`.

E.g.

```
  select new Siniflar() { 
    SinifId = s.SinifId, 
    SinifAdi = s.SinifAdi, 
    Kapasite = s.Kapasite }).ToList()
```

Note: as lazyberezovsky mentioned, your mapping seems to be flawed, as `Siniflar` does not contain the property `Ad`.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please remember to upvote any answers that you found helpful.  :)

Comment: Hi again,

I changed metod like on quesiton: loop up please...

But, I get an error again: Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Help please..